# Using arrays in str_replace

Tags: php, arrays

Is this valid PHP syntax? I think it may be causing the following warning:

`Warning: Illegal offset type`

```
$filterclear = str_replace($tag, '', $queryString);
$filterclear = str_replace(array('=+', '++', '+&'), array('=', '+', '&'), $filterclear);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP illegal offset type in multiple loop structure](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11828/php-illegal-offset-type-in-multiple-loop-structure)

Comment: Errors and warnings usually print out the file name and line number where the problem occurred... Unless that information matches these two lines, your problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine, so the only thing I can think of is that you may be using an object instead of a string in either the `$tag` variable or `$queryString` variable. I would try `var_dump()`ing these variables to ensure that they are of the right type. If they are this function is most likely not the culprit.